# Events in a JQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, events, callback, jquery-plugins

I am just starting out with JQuery plugins. I have written one this evening which works fine and does what I need it to do, however, I could do with it raising and event called "onSlideStart" at the two locations marked in my code sample below. I have no clue how to define the events or call them and i'm struggling to find anything in the JQuery docs or googling which is helping me to understand how to do this.

Would really appreciate some help with this.

```
(function ($) {

        $.fn.divSlider = function (action) {

            if (action === "next") {
                var nextSlider = this.find('.slider-item-active').next('.slider-item');
                var currentSlider = this.find('.slider-item-active');

                if (nextSlider.length === 0) {
                    return;
                }
                //SLIDESTART

                nextSlider.animate({"left": "0"}, "slow").removeClass('slider-item').addClass('slider-item-active');
                currentSlider.animate({"left": "-100%"}, "slow").removeClass('slider-item-active').addClass('slider-item');
            }

            if (action === "prev") {
                var nextSlider = this.find('.slider-item-active').prev('.slider-item');
                var currentSlider = this.find('.slider-item-active');

                if (nextSlider.length === 0) {
                    return;
                }

                //SLIDESTART
                nextSlider.animate({"left": "0"}, "slow").removeClass('slider-item').addClass('slider-item-active');
                currentSlider.animate({"left": "100%"}, "slow").removeClass('slider-item-active').addClass('slider-item');
            }

        };

    }(jQuery));
```

Comment: Does my post help? Kindly let me know if you have different use case.

Comment: Yes it does. Sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/) might help you getting started with **Custom Events**. Basically you need to [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the custom event and have an element subscribed to it with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), something like that:

```js
$.fn.doFancyStuff = function(action, opts) {
  var counter = opts.delay, timer = -1;
  var message;

  // Do something special with "action" argument here if need be
  // ...

  timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (counter--) {
      message = `${opts.gerund} in ${counter + 1} second(s)...`;

      // Triggers the custom event
      this.trigger('action:start', [message]);
    } 
    else {
      message = `You ${opts.v3} ${opts.delay} times.`;

      this.trigger('action:done', [message]);
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }.bind(this), 1000);

  // Return the instance so we can "chain" them
  return this;
}

$('span.counter')
  .doFancyStuff('dance', {
    delay: 5,
    gerund: 'Dancing',
    v3: 'danced'
  })
  .on('action:start action:done', function(e, message) {
    $(this).text(message);
  });
```

```css
.counter {
  background-color: lavender;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="counter"></span>
```

So for your case:

```
$.fn.divSlider = function (action) {
  if (action === "next") {
    var nextSlider = this.find('.slider-item-active').next('.slider-item');
    var currentSlider = this.find('.slider-item-active');

    if (nextSlider.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Triggers the custom event
    this.trigger('onSlideStart');

    nextSlider.animate({"left": "0"}, "slow").removeClass('slider-item').addClass('slider-item-active');
    currentSlider.animate({"left": "-100%"}, "slow").removeClass('slider-item-active').addClass('slider-item');
  }

// ...

$('some_selector')
  .divSlider('next')
  .on('onSlideStart', function (e) {
    // Do something

  });
```

Comment: Doh, `You danced X times` was not really right in my example. But you get the point.